# I created a file in my new rails app and when I run the http://localhost page I get a Missing Template error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

This is the error I'm getting:

**ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#index**

*Missing partial text_posts/_text_post with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],...*

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
    3 </div>
    4
    5 <%= render @posts %>
```

Here's the code in the file app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <%= render @posts %>
```

I'm following along the 'Rails Crash Course' book and this is one of the steps to create a social network. I don't know the reason for the error.

Comment: Do you create already file `_posts.html.erb`?

Comment: I don't understand where is "text_posts" come from?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `<%= render @posts %>`, i'm am sure this will call the partial file with leading `_` symbol on same directory. Please ensure you have already file with the name `_posts.html.erb`. IF you want to pass the value into partial, here i give you simple illustration :

Assume you have this in `customer_controller` :

```
def show
 @customer= Customer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then it instance will available on `show.html.erb` :

```
<p>Item: <%= @customer.name%></p>
```

These instance variables are available in layouts and partials as well, instead pass variables to partials as locals like:

```
// here is the same concept with your problem
// render "cust_name" find the filename leading with underscore
<%= render "cust_name", name: @customer.name%>
```

Above line of code will call the file with name `_cust_name.html.erb` that contains :

```
<h1><%= name %></h1>
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in your `posts_controller.rb` file you have specified the following:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

The reason why you are getting this error is because Rails is trying to display a **partial** for the variable `@posts`. What is implicit here, is that Rails is looking for a file named `_post.html.erb` in the folder `app/views/posts/` and not finding anything. To fix this, you will have to **manually create** the file in that directory (*Note that all partials begin with an underscore*).

Now, if you are wondering what you should put in this partial, first you should know what `<%= render @posts %>` is doing. When it goes to the partial, it is iterating over all your posts and for each of them, it is going to do something. So your partial may look something like this:

```
<p>
  <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post.id) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post.id), method: :delete %>
</p>
```

Just know that what is implicit here, is that we already have a `@posts.each do |post|` given for us, so you only have to define whatever content you wish to display for each individual post.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I created that file but i still got the same missing template error message. Do i have to do something else after i create the file like generate something or migrate? Also you mentioned @posts.each do |post| which file would that be located in?

Comment: never mind i got to work. thank you very much that was very helpful